# phpmailer - vendor/autoload.php issues xampp windows

Tags: xampp, composer-php, phpmailer

I've been trying different things for hours but I'm not able to fix the issue. I'm setting up phpmailer on a local xampp server on windows. I downloaded composer and ran the require phpmailer/phpmailer etc. Everything in the htdocs folder looks ok and I have the composer.json file etc.

I'm trying to run the get_oauth_token.php to set up phpmailer for gmail and it keeps giving me an error about not finding the vendor/autoload.php (the file is definitely in that directory). I've tried several different things to try and get it to locate the file with no luck.

> Warning: require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\get_oauth_token.php on line 59
>   Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\get_oauth_token.php on line 59

Answer (score 0):

Your `include_path` php.ini setting doesn't include `.`, so it will not look for files relative to the current directory. You could fix that config setting, or do this to derive a path manually:

```
require __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: Doing this gets me the following warning - **"Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\get_oauth_token.php on line 59

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\get_oauth_token.php on line 59"** how do i tell it to access the vendor folder in the root directory?

Comment: Note the direction of slashes - the examples all use Linux/macOS style `/`, but you’re on windows that uses `\\`.